# How to reduce the number of the passes in Bellman-Ford algorithm to $n/2$?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have the following problem.

> Given a directed graph $G$ and a node $S$. How can I devise a streaming algorithm to verify whether $S$ node is a mother vertex? (A Mother Vertex is a vertex through which we can reach all the other vertices of the Graph.)

The edges $(u,v)$ are being streamed.

I first solved this problem in Bellman-Ford algorithm.

1. Let the node S be the start point, the weight of every edges in the graph $G$ be $1$ and every vertex be $-\infty$.
2. Do relaxation at every edge in $n-1$ times aņd meanwhile update the number of each vertex. ($n$ is the number of vertices.)
3. Check whether there is a number of a vertex is $-\infty$. If yes, we can say node $S$ isn't a mother vertex; otherwise.

This approach needs $n-1$ passes. ($n$ is the number of vertices.) But my teacher told me that it is possible to solve this problem in $n/2$ passes.

How to reduce the number of passes to $n/2$ in this problem? Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question, but why wouldn't you just run DFS and mark connected components?